# Flutter LinearGradient transition color

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients, flutter-image

I am applying linear gradient on image, but the gradient transition is not smooth. please see the below image.

[image]

It has a line when gradient ends. how to have a smooth transition on gradient.

```
Container(
                  height: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                    boxShadow: const [BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(104, 104, 104, 0.2), offset: Offset(0, 1), spreadRadius: 5, blurRadius: 10)],
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: getImage(imageno: 123).image,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 225,
                    foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0)),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
                          Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
                          Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.65),
                          Color.fromRGBO(22, 22, 22, 0.81),
                        ],
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        stops: [0, 0.3, 0.1],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
)
```

Comment: `stops: [0, 0.3, 0.1],` must be `stops: [0, 0.3, 1.0],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of your `stops`, it should be inline changes in your stops, your last stop is smaller that middle stop and that is the problem, change it to this:

```
stops: [0, 0.6, 1],
```